# Python - Is there a way to trace back the current position of a file object by one line

Tags: python

I have a test file *(not python script)* that contains multiple sequences of the form:

**testFile *(not python script)***

```
#Gibberish
#Gibberish
newSeq name-and-details
10 something
20 something
30 something
newSeq name-and-details
10 something
20 something
30 something
#Gibberish
#Gibberish
newSeq name-and-details
...and so forth
```

Then, I have a python script that reads this file as input. For each new sequence, a new python-list is created to store the contents.

```
inputFile = open('testFile','r')
moreSeq = True
newLine = inputFile.readline()
while moreSeq:
  while (not ('newSeq' in newLine)):
    newLine = inputFile.readline()
  newList = []
  moreSeq = newList.listEntry(inputFile)
  listDB.append(newList)
```

But when the file object *inputFile* is passed to the *listEntry* method, I wish its position would point to the beginning of newSeq and not the subsequent index:

i.e. I wish it point to **newSeq #1** line, rather than **10 something**.

How can I trace back the position of file object by one line, or by a fixed measure in lines. I believe seek doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem that is normally solved by unreading the line as in the following code:

```
class SmartReader(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
       self.file = file
       self.lastline = None
    def readline(self):
       if self.lastline is not None:
          ln = self.lastline
          self.lastline = None
          return ln
       return self.file.readline()
    def unreadline(self, line):
       self.lastline = line           


     ...


    fd = SmartReader(open("file.txt"))
    readMore = True
    while readMore:
       line = fd.readline()
       if its_newSeq():
          fd.unreadline(line)
          close_the_previous_sequence()
       else:
          process_the_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file.tell()` to see the current position in bytes in the file and `file.seek()` to position the cursor to an arbitrary new position. With these 2 methods and the length of the line you just read it should be easy enough to do what you intend

```
f = open('foo.txt')
f.readline() # output `bar`
f.tell() # output 3
f.seek(0) # go to the start of the file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think same can be achieved with the following:

```
lists = []
with open('testFile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '#Gib' in line:
            pass
        elif 'newSeq' in line:
            lists.append([])
        else:
            lists[-1].append(line)
```

This will return list of lists which has the required lines. You can use any data structure you want. If newSeq name-and-details is unique then I would prefer list of hashes would be a better data structure.

Answer (score 0):

A direct solution to the problem may be to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), by doing

```
moreSeq = newList.listEntry(itertools.chain([newline], inputFile))
```

That way, the `listEntry` method sees an iterable consistent with what you described. However, I suspect that this will not solve the problem you have when `listEntry` parses the lines and returns - you probably want to rewind the file again when that happens, as `listEntry` will probably be consuming one of the `#Gibberish` lines as well.

I must say that your code reads a bit more like C than Python. I think the line reading loop would be more legible as a `for line in f` style loop. It may be a better idea to rethink your approach to align better with the language.

Comment: But using "for line in f" won't solve the problem. I could just pass the newLine to the function listEntry and get done with it, but there seems to be no way to trace back the position any fixed amount.